# Retrieving edges of a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, traversal, edges

I should create an algorithm to retrieve the list of edges (arcs) of a graph ADT.

I can't access graph private members. I have thought I could do something similar to a DFS or BFS visit marking nodes and, in case the edge exists, adding it to a list which should be the output of the algorithm but I couldn't find a solution.

I have this methods:

```
bool IsEmpty()
Node InsertNode() 
InsertArc(Node, Node) 
DeleteNode(Node) 
DeleteArc(Node, Node) 
List AdjNodes(Node) 
bool ExistsNode(Node) 
bool ExistsArc(Node, Node) 
Label ReadNode(Node) 
WriteNode(Node, Label)
```

What algorithm could I use?

Comment: mention the api's you have please?

Comment: What attributes of the graph *do* you have access to? I'm not sure how useful a graph is if you can't directly access its nodes and edges...

Comment: I have this methods:
- IsEmpty()

- Node InsertNode()
- InsertArc(Node, Node)
- DeleteNode(Node)
- DeleteArc(Node, Node)
- List AdjNodes(Node)

- bool ExistsNode(Node)
- bool ExistsArc(Node, Node)
- Label ReadNode(Node)
- WriteNode(Node, Label)

Answer (score 1):

Well, going by those methods, you can call AdjNodes(Node) on each Node of the graph. For each Node in the returned list, this will represent an edge, which can by denoted by a pair (FirstNode, SecondNode). Store these pairs in a newly created list, and that's your list of edges.

If you have an undirected graph, you will have a duplicate of every edge you find, as (FirstNode, SecondNode) and (SecondNode, FirstNode) represent the same edge.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about that, but I'm sure there's something somewhere to find the number of nodes, the OP probably hasn't found it yet.